# 300+ likes on brand new FB like button

Tags: facebook, like, button

I just added a Facebook like button to a website, and somehow it already has more than 300 likes, it's really strange because this website never had a like button on it in the past. Is there some sort of explanation as to why it wouldn't start at 0?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The likes are connected the URL. If you posted the link on Facebook and people liked it the likes will show-up when you put the Like button on your site.

Comment: Thank you, hadn't thought of that. That definitely explains it...